# Breaking out of a neverending battle without leaving the match

Tags: pokemon-third-generation

Recently, I was in the Battle Factory in Pokemon Emerald and was put up against a Pokemon with maxed out defense stats. I was using Latias, and had the opponent's attack at the minimum. Unfortunately, all my other Pokemon had fainted and we were both low on PP. Normally this wouldn't be a problem, but we were both holding Leftovers. After about 40 minutes of struggling, I did the math to see the probability of one of us getting enough critical hits in a row to end the battle, and promptly decided it was best to just forfeit and end my 70-something winning streak.

What can I do in the future to get out of such endless battles without leaving the match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did the maths and even an endless series of lucky critical hits would not be enough, there really isn't anything more you can do for that sort of situation. You would indeed be stuck in an endless loop. There is no AI programming that makes the opponent forfeit, nor are there usually ways of forfeiting the battle yourself without resetting the game. Your situation was very unfortunate and almost never happens. I've been playing Pokemon games for years and have never been stuck in a battle I couldn't win OR lose.

In the case of the opponent placing you into a situation where you cannot defeat them by battle, there are a few ways to *eventually* take them down indirectly. Such as:

- [Perish Song:](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Perish_Song_(move)) Both Pokemon in play will faint after 3 turns if they stay in play. If your Pokemon has the Soundproof ability, it will not faint from this move.
- [Badly poisoning](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Poison_(status_condition)#Bad_poison_2) the opponent with a move like Toxic: As the damage this status condition inflicts increases each turn, it will eventually knock out the opponent in one turn, regardless of what recovery moves/items they have.
- Removing the opponent's healing item with a move like [Knock Off](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Knock_Off_(move)). That way, the recoil damage from Struggle would eventually make them faint.

These solutions assume you have the Pokemon to pull them off. It could not help the situation you described but they could be cautionary means of reducing the chances of it happening again.

Comment: Well as OP stated they were in the battle factory where you use rental Pokemon so they can't create their own movesets or choose held items.

Comment: Yes it's unfortunate that this happened in the Battle Factory; my suggestions were intended for a broader range on scenarios, hence why I said it could not help the situation they described.

Comment: A series of lucky critical hits would be enough (since a critical hit did slightly more than what Leftovers can restore), but the chance that I would get enough hits in a row was infinitesimal.

Comment: I think even regular poisoning (or burning) is enough to guarantee the battle will end eventually, since Leftovers and Ingrain together (the only persistent ways to get health at every move without using up PP and without damaging the opponent with Leech Seed) only recovers enough HP to cancel out the effects of poison/burn, allowing the eventual Struggle to do a net amount of damage and faint the opponent.